# Jpa/Hibernate: error insert Entity with OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working with Hibernate and SpringBoot.

I'm trying to save an entity called Site with a siteTree list inside. This returns the following error

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        site_closure
        (path_length, descendant, ancestor) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)

o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: The column index is out of range: 4, number of columns: 3.
```

the code (in testing) is this

```
Site siteRoot = new Site(domain);

SiteClosure selfSiteClosure = new SiteClosure(0, new Site(domain), new Site(domain));

siteRoot.setAncestors(Collections.singletonList(selfSiteClosure));
siteRoot.setDescendants(new ArrayList<>());
siteRepository.save(siteRoot);
```

I have a Entity call Site

```
    @Entity(name = "site")
    public class Site {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "site_id")
        private Integer siteId;

        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ancestor")
        private Site siteAncestor;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "descendant")
        private Site siteDescendant;
 }
```

And i have a Entity call SiteTree

```
@Entity(name = "site_tree")
public class SiteTreeimplements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer ancestor;

    @Id
    private Integer descendant;

    @Column(name = "path_length")
    private Integer pathLength;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ancestor", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Site siteAncestor;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "descendant", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Site siteDescendant;
}
```

My tables in Postsgres are

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site
(
    site_id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (site_id),
)

CREATE TABLE site_closure
(
    ancestor integer NOT NULL,
    descendant integer NOT NULL,
    path_length smallint NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES site (site_id) ON DELETE No Action ON UPDATE No Action,
    FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES site (site_id) ON DELETE No Action ON UPDATE No Action,
)
```

I just can't understand what the problem is.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First correct the relationship.. Site is one to many and sitetree is many to one